# How to define T-SQL variables in Insert statement

Tags: t-sql

I have this example insert statement that used to work for copying matching rows from Table2 to Table1:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE ID='555'
```

When this statement was working, both tables had the same three columns, FirstName, LastName, and EmailAddr1.

I've since added a column, EmailAddr2, to Table1 that doesn't appear in Table2 and I want to make sure that my modified insert statement will work as I expect.

Will this accomplish my goal?

```
SELECT @EmailAddr2 = 'bill@mail.gov'
INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT FirstName, LastName, EmailAddr1, @EmailAddr2 
  FROM Table2 WHERE ID='555'
```

Comment: you should always used named inserts, never just "`insert into table`" e.g. INSERT INTO table1(col1, col2, col3) SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do:

```
declare @emailAddr2 varchar(50)
set @emailAddr2 = 'Bill@mail.gov'

Insert into Table1 ( firstname, lastname, emailaddr1, emailaddr2 ) 
select firstname, lastname, emailaddr1, @emailAddr2
from table2 where id = '555'
```